# Using SELECT and LEFT OUTER JOIN with Postgresql function

Tags: function, left-join, postgresql-9.2

I am having trouble running a SELECT within a function and getting it to return columns values from a table. The select uses a LEFT OUTER JOIN to locate values which don't match those contained in a 'master' list. So far the function looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replaceFunc ()
RETURNS TABLE (
txt   text
,cnt   bigint
,ratio bigint
)  AS $rep$

BEGIN
EXECUTE 'SELECT columA FROM Table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.A = Table2.B WHERE Table2.B IS NULL;
END

$rep$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

When I run the function, it does not return the columns I would like, only an empty replacefunc record. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What is `citynames.city`?

Comment: I updated the code to show the example in a more arbitrary manner.

Answer (score 0):

Try coding it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replaceFunc ()
RETURNS TABLE (
txt   text
,cnt   bigint
,ratio bigint
) AS $$
    SELECT columnA
    FROM Table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.A = Table2.B
    WHERE Table2.B IS NULL $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```